# 'data-clipboard-target' copying even words in the button

Tags: html, clipboard

I'm using the below code to copy text to clipboard. The error is, it's copying even the text on the button which shouldn't happen. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and the way to prevent it?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<code id='a'>https://www.tumblr.com/<button data-clipboard-target="#a">copy</button></code><br /><br />
<code id='b'>javascript:$('.overlay').slice(0, 100).click()<button data-clipboard-target="#b">copy</button></code><br /><br />

<script>var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('button');</script>
```

Comment: It seems like your just copying everything.. try to follow this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jquery to create this function you can find a demo below!

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="p1">Hello, I'm TEXT 1</p><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy TEXT 1</button>

<p id="p2">Hi, I'm the 2nd TEXT</p><br/>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the answer - It's because the button tag is within the code so it's even copying the text on button

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<code id='a'>https://www.tumblr.com/</code><button data-clipboard-target="#a">copy</button><br /><br />
<code id='b'>javascript:$('.overlay').slice(0, 100).click()</code><button data-clipboard-target="#b">copy</button><br /><br />

<script>var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('button');</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you change and why this should fix the question ?

Comment: In the question, ```button``` was in the ```code``` tag. So, copy function even copied the text in the button. That's just a minor mistake which I didn't observe earlier.